# Ansible to internally ssh to VM instance on the remote machine

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible

I have a situation where I am trying to access a remote host where multiple VNF cards are staged, now in order to perform the some linux operation on internal VNF instance, I have to SSH to VM instance with internal IP and run the desired linux commands.

e.g;  Ansible controller --> SSH1 --REMOTE SERVER1 --> on REMOTE SERVER1 --> SSH2 TO --> VNF instance - Run linux commands.

How can we automate the above operation using Ansible, any suggestion ?

I tried to create an Ansible Playbook but when I run the playbook it gets stuck. I don't find much in the log. I am assuming the below must have happened.

Ansible controller --> SSH1 --REMOTE SERVER1 --> on REMOTE SERVER1 --> SSH2 TO --> VNF instance - Failed to Run linux commands and the playbook execution fails.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure from your description but it looks like you want to use remote server 1 as a jump/bastion host. This is supported, either by setting a jump host in your ~/.ssh/config file for the given hosts (provided you use the default ssh plugin and not paramiko) or by setting this directly in ansible. You can find an example (out of many) for both methods here: https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2022/using-ansible-playbook-ssh-bastion-jump-host

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for looking into this, I am still exploring the jump server in my inventory to access the internally staged CLOUD VNF which are only accessible under private IPs.

I been trying to figure out a way to use jump server to ssh my private VNF IP where am supposed to run few configuration command in linux. 

The example explained the link you have pointed is not clear how to access the private internal IP over Jump server. 

I am keep looking, will come back if i find something on this.

Regards
Amit Kudnaver